# How to stop Alexa passing through a state to MS Azure AD?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to create an Alexa skill that authenticates to Microsoft Azure Active Directory V2.

Going through the documentation for [Azure AD V2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_user) it seems that a state is passed through, and the one that Alexa is generating seems to be way too large for MS to deal with.

```
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
```

This state seems to result in me getting the error:

> **Microsoft account is unavailable**
>
> Microsoft account is unavailable from this site, so you can't sign in
>   or sign up. The site may be experiencing a problem.
>
> You can sign in or sign up at other Microsoft Sites and services, or
>   try again later at this site.

however by fddling the url and changing the `&state=` to be *abc123*, it redirects me to the permissions page that I expect.

How can I limit the state parameter that Alexa seems to generate for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this appears to be a known bug with Alexa, where whilst Amazon have made it work for their own 1st party Microsoft account linking, the state that they pass through on 3rd party account linking, can't be controlled, and thus is too large for Microsoft to handle correctly.